# Calculating Jeffreys prior - where's the mistake?

Tags: bayesian

Below you'll find a picture with the exercise I'm trying to do do.
My doubt is in c).

I've chosen the Jeffreys Prior as the prior for N.
Also, I've modelled $Y|N \sim \text{Uniform}\{1,...,N\}$, resulting in $P(Y=y|N=n)=\frac{1}{n}I_{\{1,...,n\}}(y)$.

The problem occurs when calculating the second derivative of $log(p(y|n))$. If I assume ($y=203<n=N$), to apply the log to a non-zero value, I get $E\left(-\frac{d^2}{dN^2}log(P(y|n))|N\right)=-\frac{1}{N^2}$.

Where did I do a mistake?

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As in the text you cite, Jeffreys was (Sir) Harold Jeffreys, so Jeffreys prior, Jeffreys' prior and Jeffreys's prior would all be acceptable to at least some depending on punctuation preferences, but Jeffrey's is just a typo. (He told me himself in 1976 that he disliked the form Jeffreys'.)

Comment: Given that $N$ takes on only integral values and that $n$ must (therefore) be integral, could you explain what it means to differentiate *anything* with respect to $n$ (or $N$, as stated in the question)?

Comment: @whuber As I mentioned in my answer, it is a possible solution to switch to the continuous case to find the dedicated discrete prior, with some limitations...

Comment: @peuhp Thank you, but I do not see any justification for that in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that derivating/integrating wrt to discrete variables may be problematic. Nevertheless, considering the continuous analogous to the discrete model for derivated the associated Jeffreys is a situation discussed by Berger in https://www2.stat.duke.edu/~berger/papers/discrete.pdf (among others). Moreover, in this paper, it is stated that  the solution for your problem  is $p(N)\propto 1/N$ (first paragraph of Section 1.2.1).

However I found the same result as yours. Nevertheless (assuming that everything go well with the Heaviside step function), the alternative definition of Fisher information  gives the expected result:
$$
(\frac{d log(f)}{dN})^2=\frac{1}{N^2}
$$
Then integrating:
$$
I(N)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{N^2} \frac{1}{N} 1(y<N) dy 
$$
gives $I(N)=\frac{1}{N^2}$ and finally $p(N) \propto \frac{1}{N} 1_{R^+}(N)$.

But I do not know why (but as the switch to continuous may be a bit problematic, I would not be so surprised that some of the conditions related to the Fisher information formulation are not met)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please indicate where, in the file you put up in your answer, is the part related to my question?